# Breaking a loop when enumerating an IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, foreach, iqueryable

I have the following code:

```
var docs = ctx.Documents.Select(a => 
    new { a.ID, Content = a.Document, a.LastModified, CreatedDate = a.Created });

foreach (var doc in docs)
{
    if (Utility.ContinueDocumentPreview)
    {
        _createFile(doc.ID, doc.Content, doc.CreatedDate, doc.LastModified);
        _fireProgress(++counter, count);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The Utility.ContinueDocumentPreview flag is set to false when a user hits a Cancel button while this process is running.  The problem is when the flag is false and the code should break out of the loop, I get a SQL timeout exception.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Judging by the code you've provided, I'd say your problem is unrelated to the loop.  Have you checked the stacktrace to confirm this is related to your loop?

Comment: When you don't cancel everything runs OK? What size can `doc.Content` be?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `.ToList` to execute the SQL *before* looping, but it kind of depends on how much data you're getting in from your database.  It could result in a big SQL query all at once, so test it out a lot to make sure you're getting the performance you like.

```
// You can add .ToList() here:
var docs = ctx.Documents.Select(a => new { a.ID, Content = a.Document, a.LastModified, CreatedDate = a.Created }).ToList();

// Or, you can add .ToList() here:
foreach (var doc in docs.ToList())
{
    if (Utility.ContinueDocumentPreview)
    {
        _createFile(doc.ID, doc.Content, doc.CreatedDate, doc.LastModified);
        _fireProgress(++counter, count);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```